# TCP Options in sharpcap C#

Tags: c#, tcp, wireshark, sharppcap

I'm trying to replicate the client of a program like a VPN/Game Lobby, for make some changes, but is my first time using WireShark and Sharppcap for things like this, I hope someone can help me.

I'm replicating the first package that the client sends to the server for get a response, but there are some options that I can't find how can I configure them.

[TCP options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymz0X.png)

I can't find how to change the value of the TCP options, I would appreciate if someone could help me with this.

P.D: When I literally copy and resend the bytes of the original packet I get no response from the server. Are there any values that need to be changed to make the package "functional"?

Thanks in advance and sorry if I sound like a newbie, I am.